# mkvextract dando erro no windows

Tags: bash, shell, powershell

Instalei o **`MKVToolNix`** no meu computador e coloquei a pasta nas variáveis de ambiente.

Ao utilizar o **`MKVExtrac`** no **`Arquivo.sh`**, ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que pode estar causando esse erro?

Comment: Qual o conteúdo desse arquivo .sh? Os comandos funcionam fora dele?

Comment: Se eu rodar ele no powershell eu consigo fazer ele funcionar... Se eu conseguir dentro do arquivo.sh puxar o powershell e executar o código tb dá certo.. Tentei mas nao consegui.

Comment: Salve o arquivo como _.ps1_ ao invés de _.sh_